# Issue with <ol> <li> implementation with rails partial and cocoon gem

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, cocoon-gem

I'm having some trouble with implementing an ordered list in my rails application. I've been using the cocoon gem for a some nested forms and everything's working functionality wise, however, i cant seem to render an ordered list to make the nested form more readable.

to start my code looks like this 
_form.html.erb

```
....
      <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
          <ol>
          <%= f.label :Movement %>
                <%= f.fields_for :movements do |movement| %>
                  <li><%= render 'movement_fields', f: movement %></li>
                <% end %>
            <div class="links">
              <%= link_to_add_association 'Add movement', f, :movements, class: "pull-right d-inline-block btn btn-primary add-button" %>
          </ol>
              </br>
              </br>
            </div>
        </div>
.....
```

_movement_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <li><%= f.text_field :name %></li>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove", f, class: "pull-left d-inline-block form-button btn btn-warning" %>
</div>
```

exercise.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#exercise_workout_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });

new Morris.Line({
// ID of the element in which to draw the chart.!
element: 'chart',
// Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on!
// the chart.!
data: $('#chart').data('workouts'),
// The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values. xkey: 'workout_date',!
// A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values. ykeys: ['duration_in_min'],!
// Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the // chart.!
xkey: 'workout_date',
ykeys: ['duration_in_min'],
labels: ['Duration (min)'],
xLabels: "day",
xLabelAngle: 60,
xLabelFormat: function (x) {
date_string = x.getFullYear() + "/" + parseInt(x.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + x.getDate();
return date_string; 
},
yLabelFormat: function(y) { return y + ' min'; } 
});
});
$('#list').html('<li>foo</li>');
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.raty.min
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require raphael.min
//= require morris
//= require social-share-button
//= require html.sortable
//= require cocoon
// require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head lang=”en”>
      <title>FitnessLabs (A & K LABS)</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <%= favicon_link_tag 'logo.ico' %>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Doppio+One|Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
      <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>

      <%= render "layouts/navigation2"%>

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <%= render 'layouts/messages'%>
        <%= yield %>
      </div>

      <%= render "layouts/footer" %>

    </body>
      <script src="//load.sumome.com/" data-sumo-site-id="c5bf8251f90d125ef3264df7e976b4ab5a4a5a380ab1deaec05444284b2169d0" async="async"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </html>
```

Currently this code renders a 1. for the first list item, however, when i click 'add movement' it doesn't render the 2. 3. 4. etc. for each successive part of the form. I've tried moving the < ol> and < li>'s around but this is the closest i've come.

I want the user to be shown 1, 2, 3 etc. for each new nested form partial thats rendered, so it makes it clearer which coincides with which. How would i go about doing this? Am i on the right path?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show the movement_fields partial?

Comment: hey maxple, here's the partial code for the movement fields<div class="nested-fields">
    <li><%= f.text_field :name %></li>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove", f, class: "pull-left d-inline-block form-button btn btn-warning" %>
</div>

Comment: Ok, so when you click the add button you want a number, blank entry right?

Answer (score 0):

**Original:**

So the problem is that html before 5 doesn't render when your jquery fires to add the field.

The solution is open ended here, you use any number of technologies to solve the issue as it's not related to cocoon or rails really.

My suggestion is since you have cocoon already, just put 1 of the two options below in the custom cocoon callback files (`app/assets/javascript/`), you can use a after-insert callback to  ...

Option A

You use jquery to force ONLY the `<OL>` list to render again, allowing the HTML5 to do the rest of the work for you.  Shown in this post ... [how to "refresh" UL after adding new LI with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834014/how-to-refresh-ul-after-adding-new-li-with-jquery)

Option B

Trigger a count of the fields & inject that number in to the `<LI>` item  ... shown on Stackoverflow: [Using jQuery to dynamically refresh an ordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637205/using-jquery-to-dynamically-refresh-an-ordered-list)

---

**Update**:

I took a pretty long wack at the `recipes_controller.rb`, the model & the views.  I had to turn off kicksearch - as it wasn't worth trouble shooting to just get the controller running fully.  Non-comprehensive list of stuff ...

- I created a join table (`user_recipes.rb`) to handle look up better of recipe & users.
- I make a before_action filter on your controller for @user.  This replaces `@recipe.user` & helps with the Rails Way (allowing you flexibility in the future for devise & pundit/cancancan/whatever you eventually use to restrict access to records & pages).
- Some of your if statements for the edit / delete were not showing up, because you didn't have `.id` at the end of the `current_user`, which we fixed after going to the `@user` method
- I made a helper for `is_owner` (`recipes_helper.rb`) as there were 5 places you were testing it.  I also removed the admin? test as it's problematic where it was & just getting controller to execute.  I had to `include RecipeHelper` at the top of the controller to make it work there.
- I pulled out the validation for `user_id` from recipes, it looks like you renamed the forgein_key there to chef_id anyways ... which I wouldn't have done because it means the helper I made for `is_owner` only works for recipe_controller instead of the whole app, & makes it more of a DSL versus easily being able to look at the thing.
- I made a partial for gravatar (`views/recipes/_gravatar_section.html.erb`) & passed the `@user` in there as a local var

PS:  I'm at the point now where the recipes run enough to test the jquery against ... will update more or you can watch the updates via the forked repo [github](https://github.com/Mirv/rubyproject),

Javascript Asset stuff ...

- I did a rails `rails assets:clean` & the `rails assets:precompile` which I thought I'd mention just incase I hadn't already.
- The order of your /app/assets/javascript/application.js is wrong ... the `//= require_tree .` absolutely must be at the bottom or you're going to have issues including all the files.
- Additionally, you had two files which did not have the required, `//=` in front of them.
- For some reason, you have `app/assets/javascript/exercise.coffee` showing up in the directory & that sometimes interferes with the loading of the `exercise.js` stuff.
- I'm finding scripts in your view files instead of the assets files for javascript (not the end of the world - but makes it way harder to work with & easier to have the types of issues you're getting).
- Sumo was generating 4 errors in the chrome console, so I commented that out

Comment: Thanks so much for that @Mirv, i had all but given up hope of figuring it out. For anyone else reading i found the first method easier to implement

Comment: @J.Schimdt glad it worked - don't forget to mark the question answered - it helps stackoverflow categorize & tells people if they should read the question for help

Comment: Hi @Mirv, this will sound weird but  had the first option you gave me working, by inserting $('#list').html('<li>foo</li>'); but i have somehow managed to break it. I had to clone my project from git hub as i my computer broke and now suddenly it doesn't work. But i'm not sure what i've done. Is there any chance you could explain to me how to get option 2 to work. I find javascript very confusing and can't understand how to implement that answer to my problem.

Comment: If you had a working version I'd be tempted to stick with it & just get the env figured out.  Likely all your jquery stuff isn't working due to either the `javascript_include_tag` from `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file in the views not being in the header/missing from the `/app/assests/javascript/application.js` or maybe even a duplicate jquery file.  You should test & see if you can log to console a callback that just says, "hi" or such...as shown here by the cocoon maker ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42080359/ruby-on-rails-cocoon-gem-unable-to-capture-callback-events

Comment: I was able to log 'hi' following your advice, and also checked my files i couldn't notice anything wrong with them (I've added them to my question just incase). One thing i have noticed though is that my jquery datepicker no longer seems to work. Not sure if that has anything to do with the problem? Thanks so much for taking the time to reply to my many many questions, i really appreciate the help!

Comment: Your date picker is probably broken because you have a script included body & it should be in head...i know previously, rails could do scripts anywhere, but some where after 4 came out rails needs those scripts in the header file or you get weirdness.  Afterwards make sure to do a rails or rake assests:clean & assests:precompile ...look up syntax as I'm on cell going to bed.

Comment: Also, I'm not even sure you need that cdn jquery from body... having both might actually be your date picker error

Comment: Also, on the excercise.js ... shouldn't that 'foo' bit at the ends be closed in somewhere to be effective?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append/ ...i need to get to bed...will check in 8 hours...can you link repo if public?

Comment: Hey Mirv, thanks so much again for the help. I've tried rake assets:clean and precompile and also deleting the cdn and moving everything back into the head. So far still no luck fixing either the counter or the date picker. my repo is https://github.com/jatwell93/rubyproject/

Comment: I plugged 3 more things in the answer ... does your form save currently?  I'm still trouble shooting chunks of that to trouble shoot the jquery (recipe controller especially).

Comment: Have you ever used cloud9?  We should schedule a time to link up over skype or such...or this might take weeks/months.

Comment: wow...you are an absolute legend. i cant thank you enough for your help and expertise. i've learnt more from talking to you then i have in like my past 6 months of learning to program. As for the form it's been saving but it's been a bit buggy, which your answer explains. Also i do have cloud 9 and i've got the project on there now if that helps :)

Comment: Hey, before i forget...the code working for awhile and then breaking is a symptom of not having test coverage...look up behavior / test driven development & watch a youtube of someone talking about it.

Comment: You're doing well, don't know many beginners who bite off so much!

Comment: Thanks :). Luckily I just bought a book on testing as well!

Comment: Hey @Mirv managed to get counter working! Thanks again for all your help. I ended up giving up with the jquery datepicker and used the bootstrap one instead and all seems to be working well. I ended up merging your forked branch but i keep getting an error from the recipes helper (NoMethodError in Recipes#show) did you have this issue at all?

Comment: I don't - but ping me in a new question with your path to causing the error etc - I took a look at the controller & I add included the helper there, but nothing else is sticking out - especially if you merged!

Answer (score 0):

Found out the datepicker going bad was a jquery conflict by brute force hand testing until I got a working version.

The culprit is one of these guys ...

```
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.raty.min
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require raphael.min
//= require morris
//= require social-share-button
//= require html.sortable
```

I'd recommend slowly adding them one by one, in order of most trustworthy...till it breaks the javascript again.  Your refresh of the ordering numbers should work if try it after pulling all the items above & the datepicker too (be sure to remove the datepicker script you put in your views) - read below for more on how trouble shoot these & fix them ...

---

Rails - asset pipeline [Link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) - Javascript trouble shooting stuff ...

- First we need to decide if it's a loading issue - Open the web browser console & check `elements` for your js file names
  ... saw the cocoon was loaded under the "elements" section
- Opened the /layouts/application.html.erb file & ensured there was only one javascript_include_tag.
- Also that the javascript_include_tag was in the  tag & that the head tag is properly closed with
- Look for other non-essential or extra service loading files
  ... Sumo was generating 4 errors in the chrome console, so I commented that out
- Checked the /app/assets/javascript folder for the application.js file, also that there's no .coffee files (rails autos them)
  ... for some reason, you have `app/assets/javascript/exercise.coffee` showing up in the directory
- Check inside the application.js file ...
- Check order of your /app/assets/javascript/application.js files being loaded
  ... yours is wrong ... the `//= require_tree .` 
  ... absolutely must be at the bottom or you're going to have issues including all the files.
- Additionally, you had two files which did not have the required, `//=` in front of them.  It's required to load them
- Ensure no extra scripts being loaded in the views, I go to my working dir & `grep -r 'script' /app` & check any spot that shows up
  ... I'm finding scripts in your view files instead of the assets files for javascript ...
  If the asset asset is loading, we know it's either a conflict or poorly written code
- Insert a piece of test code in the console so when the $.document or the turbolinks finished loading to see if it's poor code
  ... they will report to console a string ("Page -- Loaded") in my case,
- If it doesn't load, it's a conflict with other java files, if it loads, it's just your code needs to be fixed
- I pull all the entries from the application.js except a test.js file (look up how to capture to log js to console)
- At this point it should work if everything before it passed ... if not you might have corrupt files 
  ... you should go into application.html.erb & use javascript_include_tag to include a CDN version of Jquery (google it)
- Assuming the test.js works ... 
  ... first, in your `app/assets/javascript/application.js`, at the bottom of the file up the `//= .` & save it ...
  ... now, you should re-add your js files to the `app/assets/javascript` one at a time, testing each time by refreshing the ...
  ... webpage, possibly restarting the server after copying the file in & doing a rake or rails assets like shown below 
  ... `rails assets:clean` & the `rails assets:precompile`